# Build once node_modules using angular CLI

Tags: webpack, angular-cli, node-modules

`Ng serve` command rebuild my node_modules each time there is a change in my code source.

```
68% building modules 1380/1406 modules 26 active ...\@angular\common\src\facade
```

It is a waste of time and I though it could be possible to specifie angularCLI to rebuild node_modules only when there is change in that folder and rebuild my /src (only my source **NOT my node_modules**) when there is change on it.

I don't know if it is even possible. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: what version of the cli are you on? angular-cli will **not** rebuild **node_modules** it needs to import angular modules that are in the  **node_modules** folder. I believe the latest version `1.0.0` has all the optimizations for faster `ng serve`

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-beta.32.3"